# access external hard drive from a different network

Tags: windows-7, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, ftp

i have an external hard drive that I have connected to an extra computer on my home network. For school and work, I spend a lot of time at another location. I'd like to access the files on my hard drive but I don't want to bring it with me.

Home computer: Ubuntu 14.04.2 32 bit
Additional computer: Windows 7 64 bit

The files are large movie files also.

Is there software or a networking solution I can use to access my drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways that you can access the files. If you wish to be able to transfer files from one system to the other, you could configure the home system to function as an [FTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) or [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) server. You would, of course, need to configure the appropriate firewall rules on the router and the home system as well, if it is using firewall software, e.g, perhaps iptables on the Ubuntu system. You will also likely need to appropriately configure port forwarding on your home router if it is using [Network Address Translation (NAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), which is the case for most home routers. You could then use the command line FTP client that comes with Microsoft Windows or a third party FTP application (there are many free ones) if you set up the system as an FTP server. Or, if you set up the home system to function as an SSH server, you could use the free [WinSCP](http://winscp.net) or the psftp program that is included with [PuTTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY), which is also free, to transfer files between the two systems.

You could also remotely control your home server by installing software on it so that it functions as a [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) server. You could then use one of many free VNC client programs, such as [TightVNC](http://tightvnc.com/) or the free version of [RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/), on the PC to remotely access the home system. Though, of course, it would be somewhat slower than sitting at the keyboard of the home system, you could effectively use your remote keyboard and mouse as if they were connected to the home system. The display for the home system would be visible on your remote Windows 7 system. You would need to open port 5900 on the router/firewall and on the home system, if it also has firewall software installed, if you use the default VNC port. Or, to have the traffic between the two systems encrypted, you can [tunnel VNC over SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol#Secure_Shell_tunneling), if you set up the home system as an SSH server.

To remotely access your system, you could also install [TeamViewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamViewer), which "is a proprietary computer software package for remote control, desktop sharing, online meetings, web conferencing and file transfer between computers", on both systems. It is a commercial product, but is free for home use. I've used it to access Linux systems remotely. The advantage of that approach is that you don't need to worry about setting firewall rules or port forwarding on your home router/firewall. And, if you've never set up an SSH server or FTP server previously, getting it up and running will take considerably less time and, since it is fairly straightforward to install and use, you won't encounter the learning curve you may have with configuring your Ubuntu system to be a FTP or SSH server.

Or are you, instead, interested in [streaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_media) the movies from your home system to the remote system?

Answer (score 0):

If your home router support it you can consider using VPN.
Instead of VPN you can simply leave your home computer On and access it via TeamViewer. 
Instead of TeamViewer you can set up a FTP Server.

My choiche is TeamViewer